# Reincarnation of the soul of the person that got hurt

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, reincarnation

I have heard and do not remember the source that a person who hurt another person willfully and intentionally in this world will have his soul reincarnated and will have to go through this world to fix it. As a result, will the soul of the person that got hurt also have to be reincarnated in this world again so that the offender can correct the injustice towards him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I foud this here: https://allparsha.org/p/102915

"The Ramak, Zohar, Reishit Chachmah (Sha’ar Anavah 5:40), Gra, and the Chafetz Chaim (S’fat Tamim, Chap. 4) all wrote that one of the primary aveirot which causes people to return as a gilgul is gezel (stealing), in order for the thief to be able to return what was stolen, to either the person or his descendants. (Mishnat HaGilgulim, pg. 393; Shome’ah Tefillah, Rav Yeshau Braver)."

Seems like from here that either the person who was stolen from must come back as a gilgul as well or it can be returned to his descendants.

Comment: Why does the person who was stolen from has to be punished to come back as a gigul, if he has not done the sin?

Comment: Because how else will the person who stole able to do teshuvah by returning the object if he has no one to return it to?! I agree it must suck for the guy who got stolen from since he did not do anything, but this is how it works :)